# Chart.JS: How to make sharp lines to smooth curved lines

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Hi I'm new at charts and this is my chartjs chart, it's working currently, but it's showing in sharp lines and I want to make it smooth curve lines on this chart. Any ideas?

```
function statistics(data) {
    if ($('#stats-currency').length > 0) {

        if (typeof(stats_currency) !== 'undefined') {
            stats_currency.destroy();
        }
        if (typeof(data) == 'undefined') {
            var currency = $('select[name="currency"]').val();
            $.get(admin_url + 'home/stats_currency/' + currency, function(response) {
                stats_currency = new Chart($('#stats-currency'), {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: response,
                    options: {
                        responsive:true,
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                              ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                            }
                        }]
                    },
                },
            });
            }, 'json');
        } else {
            stats_currency = new Chart($('#stats-currency'), {
                type: 'line',
                data: data,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                          ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                        }
                    }]
                },
            },
        });
        }
```

Comment: A smooth curve would mean different values in your graph, no?

Comment: @Snackoverflow different data values right now are being shown in zip zap lines not like smooth curve lines.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This can be done through the option [`lineTension`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#line-styling) that needs to be defined on your dataset. Choose a value below 1.

```
datasets: [{
  ... 
  lineTension: 0.8
}]
```

By default, you should however already see curved smooth lines since accoring to [Chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#dataset-properties), the default value is `0.4`.

> `lineTension`: Bezier curve tension of the line. Set to 0 to draw straight lines.
>
> Please note that if the [`steppedLine`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#stepped-line) value is set to anything other than `false`, `lineTension` will be ignored.

Comment: As of 2021-08, it seems like the default `lineTension` value is now 0, so if you're upgrading from v2 to v3 and want the same line style, you must specifically set the `lineTension` to `0.4`.

Answer (score 4):

you can do it by adding **tension** value to your charts **options**

```html
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

**JS**

```js
const config = {
  type: 'line',   // your chart type
  data: data,   // pass here your data
  options: {
    elements: {
        line: {
            tension : 0.4  // smooth lines
        },
    },
  },
};

// pass it like
  const myChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart'),
    config
  );
```

Comment: Tension is the correct name for both the options and the dataset: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/interfaces/LineControllerDatasetOptions.html#tension